# Validating checkboxes with associated select field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have a PHP Query that returns MYSQL table results in the form of Checkbox Inputs as such...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="deli_meat[]" id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['label']; ?>"  />
```

In addition, each checkbox has an associated SELECT box that becomes visible anytime one of the checkboxes in checked.

```
<select id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" class="weight" style="display:none"><option disabled selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I do this with jquery like this

```
$("input[name$='deli_meat[]']").change(function() {
    var e = $(this).val();
    $(this).is(":checked") ? $(".weight[id='" + e + "']").show() : $(".weight[id='" + e + "']").hide()
}),
```

**My Goal**

I am would to make it so, when someone clicks a checkbox and it's associated select box becomes visible, that they MUST make a selection before clicking ANY other checkbox. Any ideas how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of functionality : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiragraninga/04hpqear/)

Comment: Yes Chirag. You solved my problem. Thank You so Much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped.